# Tricky PHP Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, xml-rpc

The output for print_r($array) is as follow;

```
    Array (
            [0] => xmlrpcval Object ( 
                    [me] => Array ( [int] => 50 ) 
                    [mytype] => 1 
                    [_php_class] => 
        ) 
            [1] => xmlrpcval Object ( 
                    [me] => Array ( [string] => Angel Cook (Chamber Works) ) 
                    [mytype] => 1 [_php_class] => ) 
)
```

I only want to print 'Angel Cook (Chamber Works)', Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardcoded this would be something like the following:

```
print $array[1]->me['string']
```

Judged from the following:
You have an array... which contains entries... which are objects... which contain properties... which are associative arrays... which contain your values

Edit: not certain whether [string] is actually a key. If not... use me[0] instead.

Comment: You welcome! Consider accepting one of the answers as accepted once you've solved a problem. (Info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of objects which you want the second object (array's are zero based), where the `me` key point to an array where you want the first item so:

```
$array[1]->me[0]
```

Comment: This returned an empty string. Thanks a lot for your contribution Hailwood